# Enable input filed when checkbox is checked in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

By default the input fields are disabled, I should be enable the fields once the check box is checked. Any idea in angular 4 ?

Comment: Can you share what you have done?

Comment: Bind the checked property of checkbox and disabled property of input to a componentProperty[defaults to false], so when checkbox is checked componentProperty will become true which will enable input if you use !componentProperty with input's disabled property

Comment: @faizan any example references ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question here but make sure your check box is not bind a model which is already set to false (or default bool)

If you are simply trying to enable the check box when the checkbox is checked, you can do the following:

```
export class AppComponent {
    isDisabled = true;
    triggerSomeEvent() {
        this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
        return;
    }
}
```

and your HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myChk" id="myChk" (change)="triggerSomeEvent()" />
<input type="text" name="myTxt" id="myTxt" value="" [disabled]="isDisabled" />
```